# Speedup Prange ISD using Grover

Tags: quantum-algorithms, grovers-algorithm

In his 2009 paper, Grover vs McElicee, Bernstein proposed to use the Grover's algorithm to obtain a quadratic speedup on the Prange ISD.
However, it is not quite clear to me in which part of the algorithm a Grover search can be used and all other papers and references citing Bernstein's paper don't seem to clarify the point.
Does anyone has any idea on this point?